# ruby on rails local-variable declaration in condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, local-variables, embedded-ruby

i hope someone can help me (us). 
We`ve got a simple embedded ruby file => "index.html.erb"
In this file are 5 lines of code.

```erb
<% if false %>
    <% mylovlyvar = 0  %>
<% else %>
    <%= mylovlyvar %>
<% end %>
```

The example above works fine.
But why ????

If i comment the declaration of tthe local var in the if condition  like this...

```html
<% if false %>
    <%# mylovlyvar = 0  %>
<% else %>
    <%= mylovlyvar %>
<% end %>
```

.... i get the error

```html
undefined local variable or method `mylovlyvar' for #<#<Class:0x007f235e573090>:0x007f23606cbcb0>
```

Can someone please explain what happens in this condition with the local variable declaration.

Thank You :)

Comment: hmm what are you trying to do? can you explain a bit?

Comment: where is `mylovlyvar` declared?

Comment: @Gabbar => only in the if condition nowhere else and i only want to understand what happens

Comment: so in `else` condition you should declare local variable before display it on page.